# Assiging a variable in MYSQL based on row number

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm new to SQL so idk if this is possible, but I'm having some trouble with trying to sort a SQL. What I'm trying to doing is sorting the lastName and firstName of each member then assign there Num based on which row they would be in. I know how to sort the lastName and firstName but I'm not sure how to change the value of the Num. The photo album link shows what I'm trying to do starting from the bottom picture and going up. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit vague, but if I understand you correctly, it looks like you need a simple `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE [tablename]
SET Num = #;
```

This will change the value of Num in each row to the value listed under #. (Assuming # is actually a column and not just part of how the data is displayed. If # isn't a column, I would suggest adding a column for a primary key.)

**EDIT :**  This is not the solution. See comments for more info.

Comment: # is just how the data is display, how would I make column my primary key?(Num is actaully PK atm btw) Also sorry I was pretty vague thats why I added the pictures to help.

Comment: If Num is your Primary Key, I don't think there's a way to change it. Best thing I can think to do is move each entry to a temporary table, delete them from the original, then move them back in the order you want them in.

Comment: The problem is the user will be able to insert new members to the table and once they are done I will need to resort the table to correct it for the new user

Comment: Have you considered setting up a trigger to resort the table every time a record is inserted?

Comment: No, I don't know anything about triggers. I've only been working with MYSQL for about about a week and a half so there is a lot I still don't know about it.

Comment: I think a trigger is your best bet. If you're looking for a good intro, here's a link: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i

Answer (score 0):

```
select first_name, last_name, row_number() over(order by last_name, first_name desc) as Num
from table_name;
```

According to your requirement arrange the sorting columns and sorting order.

Comment: Tried using this after changing the syntax for my database and it's not working. Does row_number() just return the row number?

Comment: Got this issue do you know what it is?
'(ORDER BY lastName, firstName DESC) AS Num FROM testing LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0'

Comment: @ryanVincent how would I increment a variable in sql? I've never done it before and is there anything I can use to replace the over syntax?